# Finding all the possible orders of elements in a quotient group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> Let $A$ be an arbitrary Abelian group and let $H:=\{a\in A\mid\exists b\in A\mid a=b^3\}.$ Prove $H$ is a normal subgroup of $A$. Determine all the possible orders of elements in the group $A/H.$

**My thoughts:**

I've proven $H$ is a subgroup of $A$ and it is normal since every subgroup of an Abelian group is normal.
I then considered an arbitrary element $aH\in A/H, a\in A$ and tried to set some restrictions on its order, i.e., the smallest $k\in\Bbb N$ s. t. $(aH)^k=e_{A/H},$ which boils down to the smallest $k\in\Bbb N$ s. t. $$a^kH=(aH)^k= H\Leftrightarrow a^k\in H\Leftrightarrow\exists b\in A, a^k=b^3.$$
I think that $m_a:=\min\{k\in\Bbb N\mid\exists b\in A, a^k=b^3\}\le 3$ because $3$ is in that set and $a^3=a^3,\forall a\in A.$
I believe the answer would be that $1,2,3$ are all the possible orders, but I'm not sure about that so my question is how to proceed.

Comment: You are correct in your arguments so far. To finish the proof, you just need to find an example of such a quotient group with elements of order $2$ and $3$. Also, I don't think you need that the group is abelian.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim, if $b$ is an element of a generating set of the group $A$, should $b^3H$ and $b^2H$ qualify for elements of $A/H$ with orders $2$ and $3$ respectively?

Comment: No, this is not correct. Firstly, $b^3H=H$ has order $1$, no? And it is a priori hard to guess the order of $b^2H$. I am asking you to find a completely explicit group, say $\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z}$ for a nice $N$, and do the above construction, and see if you do not end up with elements of the correct order.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim, I apologize for misreading your first comment, I tried to find $N\in\Bbb N$ for which there are $k,j$ s. t. $k^2\equiv j^3\pmod N$ and $k$ itself not being a cubic remainder, but I failed. However, I found examples of $k$'s of order $3.$ $b^3H$ was really a silly mistake, I wasn't thinking.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim, I think abelian is necessary for the Normality part. This is basically the kernel of the map $x \mapsto x^3$. This is not a homomorphism for nonabelian groups in general.

Comment: $H$ is not necessarily a subgroup if $A$ is not assumed abelian. Consider $A=S_3$.  The third powers are the identity permutation as well as the three 2-cycles, all equal to their own third powers. So there are four third powers. Those cannot form a subgroup because that would violate Lagrange. On the other hand, if $H$ is a subgroup, it is automatically normal, because a conjugate of a third power is another third power.

Comment: You are of course right, I only argued to myself that $H$ was a normal sub*set*, but forgot to check that it was still a subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any element $bH$, we have $(bH)^3=H$ i.e. the order divides 3. So, the only possible case will be order 1 and 3.

Regarding the confusion about the existence of elements of the form $x^2=y^3$, note that here $x=\frac{x^3}{y^3}$, so $xH=H$ will have order 1.

Comment: Good catch! Along with OP's example of an element of order $3$, this completes the proof.